# What is the best architecture to frequently communicate values between multiple threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I am writing an application in C++14 that consists of a master thread and multiple slave threads. The master thread coordinates the slave threads which coordinately perform a search, each exploring a part of the search space. A slave thread sometimes encounters a bound on the search. Then it communicates this bound to the master thread which sends the bound to all other slave threads so that they can possibly narrow their searches.

A slave thread must very frequently check whether there is a new bound available, possibly at the entrance of a loop.

What would be the best way to communicate the bound to the slave threads? I can think of using `std::atomic<int>`, but I am afraid of the performance implications this has whenever the variable is read inside the loop.

Comment: Is it only one `int` that has to be communicated or there is a whole data structure?

Comment: in your case, I think one good option will be atomic<int> with memory order relaxed acces. Hence using `val.load(memory_order_relaxed);` and `val.store(newval, memory_order_relaxed);`. The atomic protects you from undefined behaviours, and the memory barrier avoid big  performance impact while keeping the write/read operations atomic (as in 'indivisible')

Comment: Why must a slave check **very frequently** if a new bound is available? Especially when another thread only **sometimes** encounters a new bound? Note that one thread cannot **rely** on another thread finding a bound (threads can run in any order), so these bounds can only act as an optimization. (smaller search space to explore). I agree with `memory_order_relaxed` - it's OK to miss an occasional bound. The one thing that I'm not sure about is whether your bound is a single atomic int or (likely) more. Because a pair of atomic ints isn't an atomic pair of ints.

Comment: Reading from an `std::atomic<int>` has - compiler optimizations aside - zero overhead on x86. If you need more targeted advice, I'd recommend providing more information about your application, such as relevant parts of your code, the HW you are running on (especially number of threads), problem size, performance requirements...

Answer (score 0):

Basically you could make a bet with your architecture that a single write to a primitive datatype is atomic. As you only have one writer, your program would not break if you use the `volatile` keyword to prevent compiler optimizations that might perform updates to it only in local caches.

However everybody serious about doing things right(tm) will tell you otherwise. Have a look at this article to get a pretty good riskassessment: http://preshing.com/20130618/atomic-vs-non-atomic-operations/

So if you want to be on the safe side, which I recommend, you need to follow the C++ standard. As the C++ standard does not guarantee any atomicity even for the simplest operations, you are stuck with using std::atomic. But honestly, I don't think it is too bad. Sure there is a lock involved, but you can balance out the reading frequency with the benefit of knowing the new boundary early.

To prevent polling the atomic variable, you could use the POSIX signal mechanism to notify slave threads of an update (make sure it works with the platform you are programming for). If that benefits performance or not needs to be seen.

Comment: I'd put it a bit stronger. If `int` is atomic on your platform, then using `atomic<int>` will be cheap. And when `atomic<int>` is expensive, using `int` as if it's atomic would be wrong. So just `atomic<int>`. It's not just safe, it's also the fastest safe solution.

Comment: You are missing the point: the problem is not that a write to an int might not be atomic and you could see a partial update. The problem is that the compiler is allowed to optimize away any reads or writes to non-atomic variables if it wouldn't influence the correct execution of a single-threaded program. So the compiler is e.g. allowed to turn a spinlock on a global, non-atomic variable into an endless loop or nop -  depending on the initial state of that variable. Especially writes to the bounds variable would not be guaranteed to be published to other threads.

Comment: I am actually very aware of that and this optimization could be avoided with the `volatile` keyword.

Comment: Then maybe you could mention this in your answer? Not everyone who reads your post is aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way here is IMO to not overthink this.  Just use a `std::mutex` for each thread, protecting a `std::queue` that the boundary information is in.  Have the main thread wait on a `std::condition_variable` that each child can lock, write to a "new boundary" `queue` , then signals te cv, which the main thread then wakes up and copies the value to each child one at at time.  As you said in your question, at the top of their loops, the child threads can check their thread-specific queue to see if there's additional bounding conditions.

You actually don't NEED the "main thread" in this.  You could have the children write to all other children's queues directly (still mutex-protected), as long as you're careful to avoid deadlock, it would work that way too.

All of these classes can be seen in the thread support library, with decent documentation [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).

Yes there's interrupt-based ways of doing things, but in this case polling is relatively cheap because it's not a lot of threads smashing on one mutex, but mostly thread-specific mutexes, and mutexes aren't all that expensive to lock, check, unlock quickly.  You're not "holding" on to them for long periods, and thus it's OK.  It's a bit of a test really: do you NEED the additional complexity of lock-free?  If it's only a dozen (or less) threads, then probably not.

Comment: However, why having the overhead of a mutex etc. when you can solve the problem with atomic easily?

Comment: Because what if there is more than one bounding condition?  You're not interested in just the latest update to all threads, but ALL of them.  Using an atomic just lets the threads see the latest value, which may not be enough.

Comment: @Kevin Anderson, I think that in this case we care only for the last state, not all. A mutex would have a huge overhead in compare to a single writer scenario.

Comment: @BitWhistler - and if true, then I agree, an `atomic<int>` is probably best.  But if all values are needed, then you need a bit more.  Though arguably, if you have multiple writers (each thread can write it) then what if two threads read "40" and one has 35 to write in, and one has 37?  You still run into problems even then.  35 may be correct, but 37 may get written in.  You still use atomic, but you need to use http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_compare_exchange functions too.

Answer (score -2):

This is actually very simple. You only have to be aware of how things work to be confident the simple solution is not broken. So, what you need is two things:
1. Be sure the variable is written/read to/from memory every time you access it.
2. Be sure you read it in an atomic way, which means you have to read the full value in one go, or if it is not done naturally, have a cheap test to verify it.

To address #1, you have to declare it volatile. Make sure the volatile keyword is applied to the variable itself. Not it's pointer of anything like that.

To address #2, it depends on the type. On x86/64 accesses to integer types is atomic as long as they are aligned to their size. That is, int32_t has to be aligned to 4 bit boundary, and int64_t has to be aligned to 8 byte boundary.

So you may have something like this:

```
struct Params {
  volatile uint64_t bound __attribute__((aligned(8)));
};
```

If your bounds variable is more complex (a struct) but still fits in 64 bits, you may union it with uint64_t and use the same attribute and volatile as above.

If it's too big for 64 bit, you will need some sort of a lock to ensure you did not read half stale value. The best lock for your circumstances (single writer, multiple readers) is a sequence lock. A sequence lock is simply an volatile int, like above, that serves as the version of the data. Its value starts from 0 and advances 2 on every update. You increment it by 1 before updating the protected value, and again afterwards. The net result is that even numbers are stable states and odd numbers are transient (value updating). In the readers you do this:
1. Read the version. If not changed - return
2. Read till you get an even number
3. Read the protected variable
4. Read the version again. If you get the same number as before - you're good
5. Otherwise - back to step 2

This is actually one of the topics in my next article. I'll implement that in C++ and let you know. Meanwhile, you can look at the seqlock in the linux kernel.

Another word of caution - you need compiler barriers between your memory accesses so that the compiler does not reorder things it should really not. That's how you do it in gcc:

```
asm volatile ("":::"memory");
```

Comment: This answer is wrong.  The statement "On x86/64 accesses to integer types is atomic as long as they are aligned to their size." is simply false.

Comment: @fsaintjacques, before you make such comments, you should read the about memory ordering in multi-processor machines in the Intel Software Developer’s Manual volume 3:
8.2.3.1
The Intel-64 memory-ordering model guarantees that, for each of the following
memory-access instructions, the constituent memory operation appears to execute as a single memory access:
....
• Instructions that read or write a doubleword (4 bytes) whose address is aligned on a 4 byte boundary.
• Instructions that read or write a quadword (8 bytes) whose address is aligned on an 8 byte boundary.

Comment: While you are correct that the combination of aligned storage, volatile, types of less than 64bits and manual memory barriers will do the job, it's also about the worst possible and error prone way to do it. Just use  c++11's atomics or intrinsics. They will be both, more efficient and less error prone than your construct.

Comment: @MikeMB, the worst possible way to do it, is to not know how things work. If you want a fast low level implementation you HAVE to know how things work, and then it doesn't matter do you use asm, intrinsics, or c++11 atomics. C++11 would not make it more efficient as they are just wrappers around compiler intrinsics or asm. I'd look at the generated asm to verify there are no redundant lock#s or cmp/exch.

Comment: @BitWhistler: *"...about the worst possible..."* might have been too harsh - sorry for that. But still, even experienced programmers make errors and the more code they have to write and review, the more likely it is that it contains an error, even if the programmer - in theory - knows, what the instructions do and how they interact. b) it is non portable (maybe even UB from the standard's point of view) c) You probably don't need a full compiler fence so d) it is unlikely, but you might disable valid compiler optimizations that would have made your code even faster.

Comment: I'm not saying, that there aren't situations, where writing such such low low level code is beneficial, but nothing in the question indicates, that this is the case here. Btw.: can you indicate where that article of yours can be found? Just because I strongly discourage the use of such low level primitives, it doesn't mean, I don't like to read and think about them ;)

Comment: Thanks @MikeMB, I hear you.   To me, _"I can think of using std::atomic<int>, but I am afraid of the performance implications this has whenever the variable is read inside the loop"_, sounds like wanting an improvement. I'm not sure which mechanism you had in mind that uses atomics, but if you mean to use CMPEXCH or EXCH, this will be very close to the mutex offered in the other answer. This will not scale and would perform a lot worse than a seqlock for the simple reason that a seqlock has a single writer. I will add the link to the article when I write it:-)

Comment: I was under the impression, we wouldn't need a lock at all, but just a bunch of atomics, into which the bounds get written. As reading an atomic integer has - compiler optimizations aside - zero overhead on x86 I believe this sentence was more motivated by not knowing the performance implications of std::atomics, rather than from measurements. If that assumption was wrong, please ignore everything I said and shame on me.

Comment: But that's partly my point: The OP didn't - in my opinion - provide nearly enough information about his code, compiler, number of HW-threads, performance requirements etc.to tell if those manual optimizations are worth it.